# How can i create Contact List?

Tags: java

This is my code so far:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanning all user input

// Dialogue
System.out.println("Welcome to jAddress!");
System.out.println("Please tell me your name and phone number?");
String personalInfo = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("So your name & number is " + personalInfo);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
String[] theList; // setting the type and name of the Array
theList = new String[6];// giving the array account of how many

/*Inputting the Name & Number Of Each Individual and storing it*/
personalInfo = theList[0]; // This one stores your personalInfo into theLis[0]

System.out.println("Do you Have a Name & Number You'd Like to Input? y/n");
String yesNo = scanner.nextLine();
String y = "yes"; String n = "no";
if(yesNo == y){
    System.out.println("Yay:D");
}else if(yesNo == n){
    System.out.println("GoodBye");
    //break;
}

System.out.println("Please Enter Name & Phone Number:");
theList[1] = scanner.nextLine(); //Storing Number & Name for theList[1]

System.out.println("Please Enter Name & Phone Number:");
theList[2] = scanner.nextLine(); //Storing Number & Name for theList[2]

System.out.println("Please Enter Name & Phone Number:");
theList[3] = scanner.nextLine(); //Storing Number & Name for theList[3]

System.out.println("Please Enter Name & Phone Number:");
theList[4] = scanner.nextLine(); //Storing Number & Name for theList[4]

System.out.println("Please Enter Name & Phone Number:");
theList[5] = scanner.nextLine(); //Storing Number & Name for theList[5]

System.out.println("If you want to access any name simply Press 0-5.");
int chooseContact = scanner.nextInt();
```

I managed to link both the array into the user input. So the user can manually input a name and phone number as a `String` which then will get stored in one of the arrays.

However, I want the user at the end to be able to search the array and have it print the name and phone number. For example, I want the user to input `1` which will then output the array `theList[0]` number and name.

How can I do this? I'm looking for a simple method of achieving this, such as assigning variables etc.

Comment: NOOOOOO.... don't use `==` to compare Strings in Java :_( .... use `equals`...

Comment: theList[chooseContact] that is it

Comment: In addition to Maroun's and fmodos's suggestions, you may also want to have a look at the [for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the index input by the user (+/- one depending on the case of 0-5/1-6 numbering) theList[index]

Comment: i have no idea what your refering by index? im still fairly new to java so im a bit confused. Is the index a form of method? any good explanation is well appreciated, thanks :D

Comment: well 'index' is the number used between [] these parentheses, example for theList[1] the index is '1', so if user asks for 5th value the value would be stored at theLIst[5]